# Joomla 3.2 doesn't supporting tinymce editor with "simple" theme layout

Tags: joomla, tinymce, tinymce-4, joomla3.2

In global, I have used the `"advanced"` theme layout for `Tiny MCE editor`. In a single, I used the `"Simple"` theme layout

- It is working fine upto `Joomla 3.1 version`, however it is not working in `Joomla 3.2` because of `tinyMce` upgrade to `version 4.0`.
- Is there any option to get the "simple" theme layout in the webpage.

I have used the below code for Joomla 3.1

```
tinyMCE.init({
 mode : "textareas",
 editor_selector : "mceEditor",
 theme : "simple"
});
```

Comment: I have just tested the simple layout myself using Joomla 3.2 stable and it works fine. Make sure if you're using the alpha or beta version of 3.2, that you update to the stable release.

Comment: I am using the stable version of joomla! 3.2

Comment: Oh you're importing TinyMCE, should have mentioned that before. It couple possibly be a bug, not entirely sure.

Comment: Yes, importing of TinyMCE is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always load the editor using the [JFactory::getEditor()](http://docs.joomla.org/JFactory/getEditor) method like so:

```
$editor = JFactory::getEditor();
echo $editor->display("desc", "", "400", "100", "150", "10", 1, null, null, null, array('mode' => 'simple'));
```

If not, then have a look at line 565 of `plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.php` where the script for the simple editor starts

Hope tis helps